# Datetime check in Linq where statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Please see the code below:

```
var pcPageList = db.PcPages
        .Where(m => 
            m.Quarter == exactQuarter && 
            m.Url == pageUrl && 
            m.UpdatedOn.ToDateTime().Date.ToString("dd/MMM").ToLower() == "02/nov")
        .OrderBy(m => m.UpdatedOn)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

When I run this above, the application throws error says: "ToDateTime" is not implemented yet. Anyone please can advice ?

Comment: What is the type of "UpdatedOn"?

Comment: So why do you need to convert it to DateTime if it already is a datetime type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing a string comparison, it would be more efficient to compare the date components directly.  I haven't tested this, but something like the following may work:

```
var pcPageList = db.PcPages
      .Where(m => m.Quarter == exactQuarter && m.Url == pageUrl)
      // You may need to materialize the results of the query at this point
      //   or use Convert.ToDateTime(...) instead of ToDateTime()
      .Select(m => new { Row = m, UpdatedOn = m.UpdatedOn.ToDateTime() })
      .Where(a => a.UpdatedOn.Month == 11 && a.UpdatedOn.Day == 2)
      .Select(a => a.Row)
      .OrderBy(m => m.UpdatedOn)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess this is best solution though I can't use like "02/Nov".

Comment: @coder Why do you need to match against values like "02/Nov"?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var updateStart = DateTime.ParseExact("02/nov", "dd/MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var updateEnd = updateStart.AddDays(1.0);
var pcPageList = db.PcPages
    .Where(m => 
        m.Quarter == exactQuarter && 
        m.Url == pageUrl && 
        m.UpdatedOn >= updateStart &&
        m.UpdatedOn < updateEnd)
    .OrderBy(m => m.UpdatedOn)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: this always returns null record cos m.UpdatedOn has like 02/11/2012 12:00:00 . DateTime.ParseExact returns 02/11/2012 00:00:00.

Comment: If UpdatedOn has a time component, then you need to check that it falls between two "midnights". See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should be calling `ToDateTime` using `Convert` class as:

```
  Convert.ToDateTime(m.UpdatedOn).Date...
```

And remove the `Date` in between  as:

```
  Convert.ToDateTime(m.UpdatedOn).ToString("dd/MMM").ToLower() == "02/nov"
```

Comment: this error "Execution of 'System.DateTime:ToString(String)' on the database server side currently not implemented." is still throwing.

Comment: @coder: What value you have in `m.UpdatedOn`? Also I hope that is String type. Please let me know.

Comment: I have this EG 2012-11-02 17:03:52.853